# How to calculate slope of a dataframe, upto a specific row number?

Tags: pandas

I have this data frame that looks like this:

```
PE  CE  time
0   362.30  304.70  09:42
1   365.30  303.60  09:43
2   367.20  302.30  09:44
3   360.30  309.80  09:45
4   356.70  310.25  09:46
5   355.30  311.70  09:47
6   354.40  312.98  09:48
7   350.80  316.70  09:49
8   349.10  318.95  09:50
9   350.05  317.45  09:51
10  352.05  315.95  09:52
11  350.25  316.65  09:53
12  348.63  318.35  09:54
13  349.05  315.95  09:55
14  345.65  320.15  09:56
15  346.85  319.95  09:57
16  348.55  317.20  09:58
17  349.55  316.26  09:59
18  348.25  317.10  10:00
19  347.30  318.50  10:01
```

In this data frame, I would like to calculate the slope of both the first and second columns separately to the time period starting from (say in this case is 09:42 which is not fixed and can vary) up to the time 12:00.
please help me to write it..

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the slope can be accomplished by use of the equation:
Slope = Rise/Run
Given you want to define compute the slope between two time entries, all you need to do is find:

- the ***Run**  = timedelta between start and end times
- the ***Rise***** = the difference between cell entries at the start and end.

The tricky part of these calculations is making sure you properly handle the time functions:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
```

Thus you can define a function:

```
def computeSelectedSlope(df:pd.DataFrame, start:str, end:str, timecol:str, datacol:str) -> float:
    assert timecol in df.columns    # prove timecol exists
    assert datacol in df.columns    # prove datacol exists
    rise = (df[datacol][df[timecol] == datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S').time()].values[0] -
           df[datacol][df[timecol] == datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S').time()].values[0])
    run = (int(df.index[df['T'] == datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S').time()].values) - 
           int(df.index[df['T'] == datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S').time()].values))
    return rise/run
```

Now given a dataframe df of the form:

```
    A   B   T
0   2.632   231.229 00:00:00
1   2.732   239.026 00:01:00
2   2.748   251.310 00:02:00
3   3.018   285.330 00:03:00
4   3.090   308.925 00:04:00
5   3.366   312.702 00:05:00
6   3.369   326.912 00:06:00
7   3.562   330.703 00:07:00
8   3.590   379.575 00:08:00
9   3.867   422.262 00:09:00
10  4.030   428.148 00:10:00
11  4.210   442.521 00:11:00
12  4.266   443.631 00:12:00
13  4.335   444.991 00:13:00
14  4.380   453.531 00:14:00
15  4.402   462.531 00:15:00
16  4.499   464.170 00:16:00
17  4.553   471.770 00:17:00
18  4.572   495.285 00:18:00
19  4.665   513.009 00:19:00
```

You can find the slope for any time difference by:

```
computeSelectedSlope(df, '00:01:00', '00:15:00', 'T', 'B')
```

Which yields 15.964642857142858

Comment: the line in a function where its calculating rise and run, its throwing error as "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"..

Comment: It works for me, you must be doing something differently.   Is you Dataframe column Names the same as mine?  Please post the entire error message begininng with the words Traceback as an edit to your question and format the error message as code.